AWS IAM Trust Policy Not Recognizing Principal Tag for Cognito User
I'm encountering an issue where my AWS IAM trust policy does not seem to recognize a principal tag named attribute that is present in the JWT claims passed by my Cognito user. Despite following all the guidelines and ensuring that the trust policy is correctly set up, I'm receiving an Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException with the message "Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity".
Here's the trust policy I've set up:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<POOL ID>"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/attribute": "*",
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

And here's the JWT claim data:
Claim Type: https://aws.amazon.com/tags, Claim Value: {"principal_tags":{"attribute":["0000"]}}

I've verified that the <POOL ID> in the trust policy is correctly replaced with the actual Cognito Identity Pool ID. Additionally, I've ensured that the JWT token is correctly signed and that the claims are correctly included in the token.
Despite these checks, I'm still facing the authorization issue. I've also reviewed the AWS documentation and ensured that the trust policy is correctly structured, with the necessary permissions and conditions.
I've tried simplifying the trust policy to a minimal configuration that works and then gradually reintroducing conditions to isolate the issue and found that it is not detecting the principal tag.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Well stumble on this from a google search. I'm facing a similar issue. I wanted to programmatically add tags to a session WITHOUT modifying the claims, so I went the route of using GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API. This allowed for PricipalTags to be passed in prior to assuming the role. Not only can I not find the API Call in Cloudtrail, but what should work in my conditionals in IAM using aws:PricipalTag/blah doesn't either. Wondering if you found a solution to this issue. Thanks
